# Mi aplicacion SMS no envia todos los sms que agregue a una cola

Tags: vb.net, sms

Tengo el siguiente código, lo que sucede es que cuando agrego mas de 50 SMS a la cola, solo termina enviado 45 o 44.
cuando agrego mas de 150 SMS a la cola, solo termina enviado 140, quisiera que me ayuden.
Lo que deseo que ningún mensaje se quede sin enviar, ya intente de todo pero no se que este fallando. por favor ayúdenme.

```
Imports System.Collections.Concurrent
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO.Ports
Public Class Form1
    Private Serialport As New SerialPort
    Dim miCola As New ConcurrentQueue(Of DatosParaMiProcedimiento)()
    Private lockObject As New Object()
    Class DatosParaMiProcedimiento
        Public Property Telefono As String
        Public Property Mensaje As String
    End Class
    Dim SalirDelPrograma As Boolean
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ButtonENVIAR.Visible = False 'PARA EVITAR ERRORES (ENVIO SIN  CONEXION)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonCONECTAR_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonCONECTAR.Click
        Try
            Serialport.PortName = TextBoxPUERTO.Text 'DEFINE EL PUERTO DE CONEXION
            Serialport.Open() 'ABRE EL PUERTO
            ButtonCONECTAR.Visible = False 'PARA EVITAR ERRORES (DOBLE CONEXION)
            ButtonENVIAR.Visible = True 'PARA EVITAR ERRORES (ENVIO SIN  CONEXION)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonENVIAR_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonENVIAR.Click

        Dim datos As New DatosParaMiProcedimiento()
        ' Para agregar algo a la cola:
        miCola.Enqueue(datos)
        datos.Telefono = TextBoxNUMERO.Text
        datos.Mensaje = TextBoxTEXTO.Text
        ' Para agregar algo a la cola:
        ListBox1.Items.Add(datos.Mensaje.ToString)
        Lblcola.Text = miCola.Count
    End Sub
    Private Sub miprocedimiento(ByVal Telefono As String, ByVal mensaje As String)
        Try
            Serialport.Write("AT" & vbCrLf) 'COMPRUEBA LA CONEXION CON EL MODEM
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            Serialport.Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf) 'INDICA QUE VA A ENVIAR SMS
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            Serialport.Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & Telefono & Chr(34) & vbCrLf) 'ENVIARA EL MENSAJE SIN ALMACENAMIENTO
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            Serialport.Write(mensaje & Chr(26)) ' ENVIA EL MENSAJE
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SyncLock lockObject
            Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf EnviarMensajes)
            t.IsBackground = True
            t.Start()
        End SyncLock
    End Sub
    Private Sub EnviarMensajes()
        While Not SalirDelPrograma
            Dim dpmp As DatosParaMiProcedimiento
            While miCola.TryDequeue(dpmp)
                SyncLock lockObject
                    miprocedimiento(dpmp.Telefono, dpmp.Mensaje)
                End SyncLock
            End While
                Thread.Sleep(5000)
            End While


    End Sub
End Class
```

Tengo el siguiente código, lo que sucede es que cuando agrego mas de 50 SMS a la cola, solo termina enviado 45 o 44.
cuando agrego mas de 150 SMS a la cola, solo termina enviado 140, quisiera que me ayuden.
Lo que deseo que ningún mensaje se quede sin enviar, ya intente de todo pero no se que este fallando. por favor ayúdenme.